# Hibernate @OneToOne relationship with multiple objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, hibernate-annotations

If I have a table like this...

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                         Code                         |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| id |               target_uuid              |  code  |
+----+----------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | "01BE898A-C5A9-4F86-B0AA-4ACCDCE81B8F" |    0   |
+----+----------------------------------------+--------+
|  2 | "E139F21E-8C93-492B-9E0F-CC773FAE832D" |    2   |
+----+----------------------------------------+--------+
```

...and the `target_uuid` could refer to a `Post` or `User` uuid field, how would I map this in Hibernate?

Assume `uuid` is not the primary key for `Post` or `User` here. I know, I know. Bad data model, but I'm stuck with it.

I have tried this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "uuid")
    private Code code;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Post")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post")
    @JoinColumn(name = "uuid")
    private Code code;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Code")
public class Code {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "target_uuid")
    private String targetUuid;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "target_uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "target_uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Post post;

    // getters and setters
}
```

This does not throw an exception and seems to work, but my `User` and `Post` objects keep getting NULL values for their `code` properties.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What is the "code" column for in the Code table? Is it a discriminator which allows identifying what the target_uuid is pointing at?

Comment: The code is just a magic number that means something in the business logic layer. EDIT: The code table is essentially a poorly-designed mashup of a join table and an actual data table, with 'code' being the data that a post or user cares about.

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible to map this to Hibernate, unless you can guarantee that a Post can't have the same ID as a User (in which case you could use inheritance to map this). Map this target_uuid as a String, and make two queries to find the User or the Post associated to the Code. On the Post and User side, you can have a unidirectional OneToOne association.

Comment: Well, a UUID is extremely likely to be unique. Also, both Post and User implement the same interface so is it possible to use inheritance with that? Or do I need to create a base class?

Comment: The UUID is unique, but that is irrelevant. What matters here is the ID of the Post and User entities. If they were globally unique, you could have a base abstract entity (CodeTarget), and two sub-entities (Post and User). But then you could not have a Post having the same ID as a User, since their ID would have to uniquely identify a CodeTarget.

Comment: Right. I would love to just create a unidirectional OneToOne association on the Post and User side...just can't seem to make that work.

Comment: You just need a OneToOne with a JoinColumn annotation having a referencedColumnName attribute set to "target_uuid".

Comment: @JBNizet That did it! Thanks again man...post it as an answer and I'll accept. I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, this kind of association is, AFAIK, impossible to map as a bidirectional association. You can map it as a OneToOne unidirectional association from Post to Code (and from User to Code) though, by simply setting the `referencedColumnName` of the `JoinColumn` annotation to `"target_uuid"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code implies each post is related to 1 "code". I'm not sure what the statement "target_uuid could refer to a Post or User" implies about the relationship between user and "code"? Thus, I'll focus just on "post" and "code". You also have an ambiguous statement regarding "uuid". "uuid is not the primary key f". Ok, but is it a "key"? I'll assume it is.

Let's translate:
Post has 1 "code". The means the the post table contains a foreign key:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (uuid) REFERENCES code(target_uuid)
```

The relationship is stored on the "post" table, not the "code" table.

Think of books and authors. Each book has one author. The relationship is stored with the book (not the author.)

Now the JPA (in the "Post" entity, not the "Code" entity)

```
@JoinColumn(name = "code_id", referencedColumnName = "target_uuid")
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Code codeId;
```

To summarize you need to define the relationship on the "Post" and "User" entities. Not on the "Code" entity.  Perhaps I did not understand your requirements. Hope that helps:)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I accepted another user's answer because he nailed it first in the comments, but you both said the same thing and you did a nice job illustrating it here. +1

Comment: Cool. Glad to have helped :)